# How do I export multiple header rows in Taleo Connect Client?

Tags: csv, taleo, taleo-connect-client

I am using Taleo Connect Client to export a list of candidates from Taleo to a CSV file. I want to format my CSV file to start with three header rows: A description, variable name, and data type.

```
CandidateNumber,Country,StartDate
CANDIDATE_NUM,COUNTRY_CODE,EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
VARCHAR2,VARCHAR2,DATE
10000001,US,1995-01-01
10000002,US,1997-07-21
10000003,ES,1998-11-14
```

I've tried enabling the `csvheader` option in my export, but it only adds a single header row, rather than three.

How can I make Taleo Connect Client export a CSV file with more than one header row?